# How to deal with mail senders failing on STARTTLS?

Tags: linux, email, ssl, smtp, postfix

I try to use my mail server richtercloud.de for subscriptions to vger.kernel.org mailing lists. I set up postfix 2.11 running on Ubuntu 14.04 and sending and reception works. I set up postfix to deliver mail directly to vger.kernel.org. When I sent a mail to autoanswer@vger.kernel.org the sending succeeds (mail leaves queue), but reception fails because vger.kernel.org doesn't issue a `STARTTLS` command in SMTP (relevant `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: connect from vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? [::1]/128
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? [::1]/128
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.62/32
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.62/32
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.23/32
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.23/32
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.62
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.62
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.23
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.23
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: vger.kernel.org: no match
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: 209.132.180.67: no match
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/anvil
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: send attr request = connect
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: send attr ident = smtp:209.132.180.67
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: status
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute value: 0
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: count
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute value: 1
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: rate
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute value: 1
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: (end)
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 220 richtercloud.de ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: EHLO vger.kernel.org
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: vger.kernel.org: no match
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: 209.132.180.67: no match
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-PIPELINING
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-VRFY
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-ETRN
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-STARTTLS
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250-8BITMIME
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250 DSN
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: MAIL From:<> BODY=8BITMIME SIZE=1778
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: RCPT To:<richter@richtercloud.de> NOTIFY=FAILURE ORCPT=rfc822;richter@richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: DATA
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Oct  5 12:55:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:58:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: NOOP
Oct  5 12:58:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 250 2.0.0 Ok
Oct  5 12:58:24 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: watchdog_pat: 0x2cbb60d8
Oct  5 12:58:41 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[28022]: connect from hermes.apache.org[140.211.11.3]
Oct  5 12:58:42 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[28022]: disconnect from hermes.apache.org[140.211.11.3]
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: < vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: QUIT
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: > vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? [::1]/128
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? [::1]/128
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.62/32
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.62/32
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.23/32
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.23/32
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.62
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.62
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? 192.168.178.23
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? 192.168.178.23
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostname: vger.kernel.org ~? richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_hostaddr: 209.132.180.67 ~? richtercloud.de
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: vger.kernel.org: no match
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: match_list_match: 209.132.180.67: no match
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: send attr request = disconnect
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: send attr ident = smtp:209.132.180.67
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: status
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute value: 0
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: input attribute name: (end)
Oct  5 12:59:13 richtercloud postfix/smtpd[27539]: disconnect from vger.kernel.org[209.132.180.67]
Oct  5 13:02:33 richtercloud postfix/anvil[27581]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.132.180.67) at Oct  5 12:55:24
Oct  5 13:02:33 richtercloud postfix/anvil[27581]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.132.180.67) at Oct  5 12:55:24
Oct  5 13:02:33 richtercloud postfix/anvil[27581]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Oct  5 12:58:41
```

). I guess this sort of behavior might be an issue for a number of senders.

`postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_list = vger.kernel.org
home_mailbox = .Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = richtercloud.de, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = richtercloud.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.178.62/32 192.168.178.23/32 192.168.178.62 192.168.178.23 richtercloud.de
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter =
relayhost = smtp.elasticemail.com:2525
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_enforce_peername = no
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_enforce_tls = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit_tls_clientcerts
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

`telnet richtercloud.de 25`:

```
Trying 192.168.178.76...
Connected to richtercloud.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 richtercloud.de ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo richtercloud.de
250-richtercloud.de
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

I assume that such a command has to be issued in order to avoid my server becoming an open relay and I don't understand why vger.kernel.org doesn't do it. How can I enforce secure transmission in SMTP, i.e. receive a replay to a message to autoanswer@vger.kernel.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STARTTLS has nothing to do with open relay:

- Open Relay: accepts and delivers mail for recipients not in the local mail domains. This can be used to spread spam to external recipients and you usually get quickly get blacklisted.
- STARTTLS: encrypt the connection with TLS so that nobody can listen or manipulate the data send.

You can restrict recipients to your own mail domains without STARTTLS and you can be an open relay even if you use STARTTLS.

How to deal with senders not using STARTTLS:

- If you want to have encrypted transport you have to accept that some will not use encryption and loose this traffic. But in this case you should also better do it correctly and not use a self-signed certificate like now, because this is open to man-in-the-middle attacks.
- Or consider encryption optional, that is don't enforce it by setting `smtpd_enforce_tls = yes`.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't enforce TLS. Enforcing it on a public SMTP server violates [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207), which sets the rules on how to use the `STARTTLS` extension:

> A publicly-referenced SMTP server MUST NOT require use of the
> STARTTLS extension in order to deliver mail locally.  This rule
> prevents the STARTTLS extension from damaging the interoperability of
> the Internet's SMTP infrastructure.  A publicly-referenced SMTP
> server is an SMTP server which runs on port 25 of an Internet host
> listed in the MX record (or A record if an MX record is not present)
> for the domain name on the right hand side of an Internet mail
> address.

Comment: While your statement is true, sending anything even remotely important over the internet in the clear is considered very bad practice nowadays and shouldn’t be encouraged. (There’s also [RFC 7258 / BCP 188](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7258) on this for people set on having this packaged up in official writing.) – The quoted passage made sense at the time, that is in 2002, but at this point its pretty fair to say its a historic relic that probably only can be fixed by sysadmins/companies voting with their feet and creating facts by ignoring it.